# Unable to click yahoo mail delete button

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I am beginer to Watir and trying to delete yahoo mails using webdriver

```
require "rubygems"
require "watir-webdriver"

br=Watir::Browser.new :ff
br.goto("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login_verify2?&.src=ym")
br.text_field(:id,'username').set("xxxx")
br.text_field(:id,'passwd').set("xxxx")
br.button(:id,'.save').click
sleep(5)
br.button(:value=>"Check Mail").click
br.checkbox(:title=>"Select or deselect all messages [Ctrl+A]").click
br.button(:id=>"yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806292").click
```

The click is not working for **delete** button
**br.button(:id=>"yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806292").click**

Requesting help.Thanks in advance

html code is below

```
<div class="list-view-footer" role="toolbar" id="yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806297">
<div id="yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806296" class="commontasks shaded">
<div id="pagetoolbar" class="">
<span id="yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806293" class="btn left right multimsg">
<a id="yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806292" data-action="delete" title="Delete selected emails [Delete]" href="#" role="button">Delete</a>
</span>
<span class="btn left onemsg" id="yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806444">
<span id="btn-reply" class="btn right menu onemsg" data-action="menu">
<span class="btn left onemsg">
<span class="btn multimsg">
<span id="btn-move" class="btn menu right multimsg" data-action="menu">
<span id="btn-ml-preview" class="btn left right menu" data-action="menu">
<span id="btn-actions" class="btn left right menu" data-action="menu">
<div class="rht pagination shaded" role="presentation"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use link instead.

```
br.link(:id=>"yui_3_2_0_1_13307738172806292").click
```

And now for some unsolicited advice since you are so Gung Ho to do this right (which I admire in newbies). First, I would not use any sleeps unless I absolutely had to. Instead wait for the thing you are looking for:

```
br.button(:value=>"Check Mail").wait_until_present
```

Next, be careful about using platform specific identifiers. In this case, my system is a Mac so "Select or deselect all messages [Ctrl+A]" is "Select or deselect all messages [Cmd+A]" on my system. It doesn't work. An alternative is to use a partial string:

```
br.checkbox(:title=>/Select or deselect all messages/).click
```

It's a good idea to pick the right identifier(s) and stay with them where possible. Here I am using title for both. If you test a system that is not localized, title may be a bad choice.

```
br.checkbox(:title=>/Select or deselect all messages/).click
br.button(:title=>/Delete selected emails/).click
```

Good luck.

Comment: I agree with what Dave has here with one potential change.  Normally I love using ID to identify stuff, provided it is predictable. I would however be wary of ID values that look like the above.  Often times they are generated on the fly and are not consistent from one run to the next.  So you might have to select the delete link like this `br.link(:text => "Delete").click`  Button only work for clicking a link if there is an image defined (instead of text) for the link.

Comment: Yes, the yahoo id's look sketchy at best.

Comment: Thanks Dave and Chuck for valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML of yahoo mail Delete button as follows:

Delete

I have observed that id="yui_3_2_0_1_13426820823723547" is dynamic (some last digits are changed). So the following xpath can be used:

//a[starts-with(@id, 'yui_3_2_0_1_')]
If this is failed you can use the following xpath:

//a[@title='Delete selected emails [Delete]']